# Python regex to get non http(s) urls from <a> tag from html content

Tags: python, html, regex, url

I am trying to fetch non-http(s) urls from anchor tag. I need to match the entire anchor tag if such an url is found.

#### Example :

This should match: `<a href="example.com/index.html"> bla</a>`

This shouldn't match: `<a href="https://www.google.com/">bla2 </a>`

I have been able to build this regex so far:

```
(\<a[\s\S]*?)(?<=href)(?:(=[\"\'])|(=))(?!(http[s]?)|(ww[w]?)|(#)|(\/\/))
(?P<url>[\S]*?)(?=([\"\'])|(\s))([\s\S]*?\>)
```

But this gives me a match even for the one with HTTP.

With this regex : `(?<=href=[\"\'])(?!(http[s]?)|(ww[w]?))(?P<url>[\S]+)(?=[\"\'])` I am able to get only the non-http url but i need the entire content of `<a>` tag getting matched, too.

Any suggestions would be great. Happy if this can be further improved.
PS: I can not use beautifulsoup. So please suggest a better regex for my problem.

Comment: You cant parse html with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: don't use regex, use a HTML-parser.

Comment: I know it isn't a great idea to use regex for html, but i am constrained to do it by making use of regex. HTML parser wouldn't help me much. Any suggestion on modifying the regex to get what i need would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
(<a[^>]*href=[\"\'](?!http|ww)(?:\S+)[\"\'][^>]*>)
```

This will match `<a href="example.com/index.html">`, if you need everything until `</a>` then add e.g. `.*?</\s*a>` before the closing parenthesis.

#### Explanation

- `(?!http|ww)`: negative lookahead, actually `https?` is unnecessary here because `(?!http)` will already match both `http` and `https` (same for `ww` and `www`)
- `(?:\S+)`: url. This could be improved, since many symbols aren't allowed in URLs, but it is sufficient for the moment.
- `[^>]*` a might potentially contain other stuff.

Comment: Thanks.. This almost works.. But it wouldnt match non-quoted urls like
<a href=google.com > Is there any ways i could match this too??

Comment: Maybe `(<a[^>]*href=[\"\']?(?!http|ww)(?:\S+?)[\"\']?[^>]*>)`. Also change the `\S+?` to a pattern that matches a URL good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your time, This does match unquoted urls but it also matches urls starting with http/www though we have written negative lookaheads.. This has been the case for me too.. If i try to match unquoted urls https too gets matched.. If i try to make it not match https, even the unquoted urls also gets missed.

Comment: yeah sry, wasn't thinking. How about `(?:h(?!ttp)|w(?!w)|[^wh])\S*` instead of `(?:\S+?)`? This would match strings that do not start with `http` or `ww`. And then the optional quotes and stuff around as above.